How to understand isomorphic structures example 2.7 from Wei Li Book
In The book: Mathematical logic by Wei Li, site 50-51, the example 2.7 explains the isomorphic structures.

But when I map the succssor function, I get the following:

$$\pi(S_N(a_3))\stackrel{?}{=} S_{N_{even}}(\pi(a_3))$$
$$\pi(S_N(\sigma_1(a_3)))\stackrel{?}{=}S_{N_{even}}(\pi(\sigma_2(a_3)))$$
$$\pi(S_N(3))\stackrel{?}{=}S_{N_{even}}(\pi(6))$$
$$\pi(4)\stackrel{?}{=}S_{N_{even}}(12)$$
$$8\stackrel{?}{=}24$$

I need to know what is false with my interpretation, can any one help me please ?

It's a typo. $s'$ should be defined by $s'(x)=x+2$.
Also, the formula you're checking is incorrect. It should be $$\pi(S_N(\sigma_1(a_3)))=S_{N_{even}}(\pi(\sigma_1(a_3)))=S_{N_{even}}(\sigma_2(a_3))).$$
You wrote $\pi(\sigma_2(a_3))$. This doesn't make sense, because $\sigma_2(a_3)$ lives in $N_{even}$, but $\pi$ is a function $N\to N_{even}$.

When it is a typo, then in the fifth-step: $$8\stackrel{?}{=}14$$, it is false too

Right. The author made a mistake, and so did you! I've edited my answer to point out both mistakes.

After this question i was banned to ask another question, therfore i have deleted the comment, i still banned to ask another quesion!!!, Do you have another idea, what can i do?
